# Can I specifically disable PATCH in spring-data-rest repository?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Client of our API's don't use patch and I want to avoid it for maintenance overhead. I don't want to disable POST or PUT.

Comment: Simplest option is probably to handle at the HTTP level either using Spring Security or a simple Servlet Filter that rejects all PATCH requests.

Answer (score 2):

It can be handled at the security level, by extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (available in [spring-security-config](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config)) and overriding `configure(HttpSecurity http)` to deny PATCH requests to the target url :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/path_to_target_url").denyAll();
    }

}
```

Any attempt to PATCH to the target URL will fail with a `401 Unauthorized` error.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is necessary to put the plug in the REST controller... For example:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/...")
@ExposesResourceFor(...)
public class MyController {
...
    @PatchMapping
    HttpEntity<?> patch() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
    }
}
```