# Export PATCH/PUT but not POST in @RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using `spring-data-rest` and exposing endpoints for CRUD-ing my entities through repositories.
One of entities should be updatable with PATCH/PUT methods, but it shouldn't be possible to create a new instance with POST method.

It seems that both actions go through `save` method so it seems not possible to export only some of the requests:

```
@RestResource(exported = ?)
@Override
<S extends User> S save(S s);
```

What's the best way to accomplish that?
Should I override `save` method? Write custom `Validator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

- [Validators](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#validation) and add an Error to the `errors` parameter
- [Event Handlers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events), throw an Exception and catch that by `@ControllerAdvice`, which returns a custom Message or HTTP status code
- [Custom Controllers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) and handle the request manually. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41351429/7226417

The first two should listen to `BeforeCreateEvent`.

Comment: Using either of those solutions will cause that OPTIONS request will return "Allow: POST,..." in headers which isn't true, correct?

Comment: I think so. I added a third option, where you can also manipulate the OPTIONS-Mapping.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (available in [spring-security-config](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config)) to deny access for POST requests to the target url :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/path_to_target_url").denyAll();
    }

}
```

Any attempt to POST to the target URL will fail with a `401 Unauthorized` error.